# How to get a specific value out of a loop in JQuery - wordpress queried post

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a question about being able to get values out of the hidden input boxes in this:

```
<?php  $i = 0; $j = 1;?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
        $postid[$i] = get_the_ID();
        echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$postid[$i]."' id='hiddenpostitle".$j."' name='hiddenpostitle'/> ";
        echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$j."' id='hiddenpostnumfield".$j."'/> ";            
    ?>
    <?php 
        $i++;
        $j++;
    ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

So what this does is draw in all the post and formats them according to Wordpress.  While each post is looped I create 2 input boxes for each, one with the post id with a incremental variable and one that stores the value of the above input box with an incremental variable.  I am making a product overview so I need to be able to access the proper post and have that sent using JSON.

The part that I am stuck on is the getting the correct post type that was clicked.

Here is my JQuery code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.item-post a').each(function (i) {
        $(this).on("click", function (e) {
            alert(i);

            var num = $('#hiddenpostitle').val();
            alert(num);

            var prodname = $('#hiddenpostitle' + num /* + (i+1)*/).val();

            $.post('overviewcheck-515adfzx8522', {'ProdName': prodname}, function (response) { }, 'json');
        });
    });
    $('.item-post a').colorbox({ opacity: 0.3, href: "../overviewa512454dzdtfa" });
});
</script>
```

This is not working properly because it will always give me the first post there is because I am not getting the associated product that was clicked.

Example:  lets say you click 3 and 1 is first,  you will always get 1 even if you click 2 or 3 or 4.

I am really stuck and need help on this. Not to sure how to proceed.

Merry Christmas!

UPDATE:

new Code being used

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post-id-holder">
      <?php get_template_part('content',get_post_format()); ?>
      <div class="post-id-data" post-id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" post-title="something"></div>
      </div>                        

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
(document).ready(function() {
   $('.item-post a').click(function(){
    // find the article for the post
    var article  = $(this).parentsUntil('article').parent();
    var post_id = article.attr("id");
    var post_title $('.entry-title a',article).text();
    alert(post_id);
    alert(post_title);


    $.post('overviewcheck-515adfzx8522', 
    { 
    'ProdName': prodname

    },
    function(response) {
    },
    'json'
    );


   $('.item-post a').colorbox({opacity:0.3, href:"../overviewa512454dzdtfa"});
   });
});
```

ANSWER:

Thanks Matt! :)

Here is the code, so if you ever run into this you can use it!

Wordpress Queried section:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <div class="post-id-holder">
 <?php get_template_part('content',get_post_format()); ?>
  <div class="post-id-data" post-id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" post-title="something">      </div> 
 </div>                     

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

JQuery Side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.item-post a').click(function(){
    // find the article for the post
        var article  = $(this).parentsUntil('article').parent();
    var post_id = article.attr("id");
    var post_title = $('.entry-title a',article).text();



        $.post('overviewcheck-515adfzx8522', 
                                        { 
        'ProdName': post_title

                                        },
         function(response) {
                                        },
         'json'
        );



       });
    $('.item-post a').colorbox({opacity:0.3, href:"../overviewa512454dzdtfa"});
});

</script>
```

Again thanks everyone!  Merry Christmas!

Comment: that code is really hard to read, can you clean up the indents

Comment: Ya I am very sorry about that, thanks to whoever edited it :) let me know if you can give me a hand

Comment: You're looking for `var num = $('#hiddenpostitle').val();` and not something that connects the anchor to the post. There would/should only be one `$('#hiddenpostitle')` so you're always going to return that value. It would probably be helpful to see a simplified version of the html regarding the anchor and the post to get an idea of the structure.

Comment: I want to answer but my kid won't let me put her down. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't a need to use an input tag if you are not creating a form. It will just cause issues if by chance your code is executed inside a form block. If you just want to discover the post-id at javascript time, then it's better to stuff it into a property of a div or span tag.

```
<?php while(have_posts()): ?>
<?php the_post(); ?>
<div class="post-id-holder">
    <?php get_template_part('content',get_post_format()); ?>
    <div class="post-id-data" post-id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" post-title="something"></div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Later you can access it via javascript as such.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.item-post a').click(function(){
      // where are we? we are at any link inside the post, and that's no good.

      // find the holder parent
      var holder = $(this).parentsUntil('.post-id-holder');
      var data = $(".post-id-data",holder);

      var post_id = data.attr("post-id");
      var post_title = data.attr("post-title");
   });
});
</script>
```

EDIT:

After reviewing the HTML, I think you can get the post ID and title without having to add anything to the template.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.item-post a').click(function(){
      // find the article for the post
      var article  = $(this).parentsUntil('article').parent();
      var post_id = article.attr("id");
      var post_title $('.entry-title a',article).text();
      alert(post_id);
      alert(post_title);
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is giving me a `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'parentsUtil'`

Comment: Hey so once I run this I print out the post_id, and it tells me undefined.

Comment: Can you put a sample of the HTML in http://pastebin.com/ because it's really hard to understand the DOM structure with out knowing what the wordpress template is generating.

Comment: @DavidBiga thanks, but I meant the outputted HTML not the source.

Comment: @DavidBiga you can xxxx out anything that might be private.

Comment: like what happens?  if you wanna see it live go to prodjsoundlighting.com

Comment: click on the products on the homepage, the post underneth packages

Comment: @DavidBiga thanks, that makes it a lot easier. I modified my answer. I "think" this should work, but I often struggle with the parentsUtil feature of jQuery.

Comment: Alright so I tried adding in the JQuery code you made edit to while I still have the html code you gave me...I'll make an edit in my post and you can see...but it is giving me an error on `var post_title $('.entry-title a',article).text();`

Answer (score 1):

May be not an answer to your question but first of all you shoud remove the `each` part from here

```
$('.item-post a').each(function (i) {
    $(this).on("click", function (e){
        //...
    });
});
```

It should be

```
$('.item-post a').on("click", function (e){
    //...
});
```

You should register your event outside of each, doesn't need to loop, `jQuery` will do it. Also you are using following code

```
$.post('overviewcheck-515adfzx8522', {'ProdName': prodname}, function (response) { 

}, 'json');
```

In this case the first argument doesn't look like a valid `url` and the callback function is doing nothing at all, so You should fix these.

Comment: How should I go about this?  Also what about what the guy said below you?